# 7z doesn't handle deleted files after archiving started

Tags: 7zip

I am zipping a folder through an antrun command with `7zip` and while the command is running, there are some temporary `*profile.gz` files that are deleted, this causes the `7zip` to show a series of warnings that it cannot find the deleted files. Is it a switch to ignore the missing files? I assume that before starting the compression, 7z collects a list of files that need to be archived.

Comment: Did you try the `-x (Exclude filenames) switch`? So the list of files to archieve doesn't even contain the temp files? If you know the names (or a pattern) beforehand.

Comment: @xander There still remains one `proifile.gz` file which needs to stay, also the name of the profiles contain timestamps in them, so I wouldn't know which one to keep.